# knp_pagination_bundle - using routing instead of query parameters

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm using knp_pagination_bundle, the newest version.
I want to generate URLs like

```
fooroute/page/3/sort/id/direction/desc
```

Instead of default

```
fooroute?sort=id&direction=desc&page=3
```

I need only help with configuring knp_pagination_bundle. I can do routing myself.